# How to batch files in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I would like to build a shell script to automatically archive object files into a static library, and copy all the headers and .a file to desired directory.

However, as the number of obj files grows, the following mess gets worse:

```
8  CWD=$(pwd)
9 
10 FILE1="SDL_Logger.o"
11 HEADER1="SDL_Logger.h"
12 FILE2="SDL_Initializer.o"
13 HEADER2="SDL_Logger.h"
14 ARC="libsdlhelper.a"
15 
16 INCLUDE=~/include
17 LIB=~/lib
18 
19 if [ ! -f $FILE1 ];
20 then
21     echo " error: file $FILE1 does not exist. Abort."
22 else
23     if [ ! -f $FILE2 ];
24     then
25         echo " error: file $FILE2 does not exist. Abort."
26     else
27         echo " building archive... "
28         ar rs $ARC $FILE1 $FILE2
29 
31         # lib
32         cp $ARC $LIB
34 
35         # include
36         cp $HEADER1 $INCLUDE
37         cp $HEADER2 $INCLUDE
39 
41     fi
42 fi
```

So, if I were to group all files into ONE variable like:

```
FILE="obj1.o obj2.o ... "
```

How would I check the existence of each file, and copy them(headers)? I can only do this one by one, which will be soon unacceptable.

Comment: You might be happier using make, the tool designed for this job.

Comment: Is there a problem with using `for` loops? Do you know about them?

Comment: Yeah, Makefiles are the way to go. Or a similar build system, like SCons, CMake, probably others.

Comment: I had no idea how Make could get involved in copying files to other directories. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I thought archiving files had nothing to do with Make, logically, so intuitively I came up with the idea to put them in a shell script, as I would do that in a shell, if not using script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with to help you.
The best way to do this is using an array for FILE

short example to implement what you are trying to do:

```
# !/bin/bash

#define an array of files to look for
FILES=("SDL_Logger.h" "SDL_Initializer.h" "libsdlhelpere.o")

#define your directories
INCLUDE=~/include
LIB=~/lib

#set the amount of entries in our array
SIZE=${#FILES[@]}

# use for loop read all FILES
for (( i=0; i<${SIZE}; i++ ));
do
    echo "checking for file: "${FILES[$i]}

    if [ ! -f ${FILES[$i]} ];
    then
        echo " error: file"${FILES[$i]}" does not exist. Abort."
        else

           echo " building archive... "
       fi

done
```

Here we define FILES as our array

```
FILES=("SDL_Logger.h" "SDL_Initializer.h" "libsdlhelpere.a")
```

then we Find the size of files

```
SIZE=${#FILES[@]}
```

Then we go through each file and execute a command which is echo and then our if statement:

```
for (( i=0; i<${SIZE}; i++ ));
do
```

Here is how we call our item in the array...

```
${FILES[$i]}
```

so in what we are doing in plain english is:

```
echo FILES[1].... 
IF FILES[1] doesn't exist then error.... 
else execute building archive... 
echo FILES[2].... 
IF FILES[2] doesn't exist then error... 
etc...
```

This will repeat until the SIZE of FILES in met.

Using this method you can also just define the beginning part of the file name such as
"SDL_Initializer" and have your loop add in the .o .h. .a etc... Maybe another array FILETYPES ;)

hope this helped...
Sorry I didn't complete the code for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Believe it or not I had no idea about for loops in shell, yea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to the question as asked:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="SDL_Logger.o SDL_Initializer.o"
HEADERS="${FILES//.o/.h}"
ARC="libsdlhelper.a"
INCLUDE=~/include
LIB=~/lib

for f in ${FILES}; do
  if [ ! -f "${f}" ]; then
    echo "error: file ${f} does not exist. Abort."
    exit 1
  fi
done

ar rs ${ARC} ${FILES}
cp ${ARC} ${LIB}
cp ${HEADERS} ${INCLUDE}
```

However, as the comments point out, the right tool for this job is make. For example [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/). If you plan on developing software on a unix platform, investing time learning make is time well spent.